# Send object embed sfw to the back

Tags: html, css

I need to know the following...

I have a video embed in html using  tag, the page that I'm building is using the z-index, the idea is to use layers... everything was fine until, the media embed...

I have a video on full screen 100% width and height ...

```
<style>
.bg_vid {
  position: absolute;
z-index 10;
w: 100%
h: 100%
}

.btns {
position: relative;
}
.btn-overlay-vid {
bg: url'img/pattern.png';
position: absolute;
z-index: 30;
}

.btn-video {
z-index: 25;
}
</style>


<div class="btns">
<div class="btn-overlay-vid"></div>
<div class="btn-video">
<object width="300" height="169">
<params name [...]> </params>
<params name [...]> </params>
<params name [...]> </params>
<params name="wmode" value="transparent" > </params>

<embed [...]&embed=transparent ></embed>
</object>
</div>

</div>
<div class="bg_vid">
<iframe [...] />
</div>
```

So the background video for the full "screen" is working fine, but, the button video is not working... I mean the overlay div still behind the  now this only happen for almost all browsers but Google Chrome .. in Google Chrome is working good...
the video is behind the overlay div which is just an image for(for now), so I wonder why in IE(not surprise there) and Firefox is not working...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving .btn-video a position, relative or something. z-index doesn't like undeclared positions.

Comment: Hello, I have put a relative position to the div with the video, and a absolute to the div with the image, but no luck.... also at Adobe Flash Object [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values) it say that I can use wmode=opaque to over lap other elements in my site such as this case, but is not working... only in Google Chrome... Thank you...

Comment: Darn, sorry. I was having a similar issue just now on my site and i thought it might help ^^;

Comment: No problem... if the site I'm trying to build is not staked div's all my div's has to be overlap... and I'm calling each div with some jQueries ... all is working fine except for this part where I need to use <object> embed ... I can not use <iFrame> because that tag is use for other purposes in the page with java and some other effects... any way... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my Java that I was using for the  tag... and by doing so, I can now use &wmode=transparent in my , Say I want to send the iFrame to the background of any other layer...

```
<iframe 
class="behind" 
type="text/html" 
width="300" 
height="169"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7SyAejEiiLw?autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now I can dance like the guys in that video...

**Note:** If you want to use the "Params" like in this demo I suggest you use the YouTube API instead, it will work as standalone but is always better to use the API, more control over the YouTube Player.

So my conclusion to this is NEVER limit an HTML TAG, I was reserving the iframe tag for other purposes and by doing so I was forcing my self to use the object tag for media files, also was limiting the use of my site on other devices such as tablets or smartphones, the  tag is not so friendly with those devices.